# Calendar Bolded Dates

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, calendar

I have a button in every row of my DataGridView.  When that button is clicked, a calender should be displayed in which the selected dates (I have in list) should be bolded.  The dates will be different for different buttons and so the bolded dates should also be changed for every button click. Is it possible to have a tag for every bolded date?

Is the single calender is sufficient or should I declare number of month calenders for every button.

I am very new to C#, please reply me the answer.

Comment: +1, good question. But not possible to add tags for each and every bold dates by using the default members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the same Calendar control by specifying different `BoldedDates`.

```
DateTime[] myDates = {myDate1, myDate2};
calendar.BoldedDates = myDates;
```

Look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9a9k6dd.aspx) and [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/monthcalendar) for more details about bold dates.

Comment: Can I keep tags to those bolded dates

Comment: Tags in the sense? Tag property?

Comment: yeah.If we focus on that bolded date,is it possible to display some tag(message) about that bolded date?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with default properties.